# ActiveRecord collection count when ordered by joined field gives Mysql2::Error: Unknown column in 'order clause'

Tags: mysql, ruby-on-rails-4

Attempting to call count on an ActiveRecord::Relation collection works fine, unless you left join it as follows:

```
users = User.joins(:foos).select(['users.id as id', 'users.name as name', 'sum(b.blah) as blah', 'max(foos.baz) as bazness']).
          joins('left join tabley_things b on users.id = b.user_id').group('users.id')

users.count # no problem
users.order('name DESC').count # no problem
users.order('bazness DESC').count # no problem despite it being joined
users.order('blah DESC').count # AUGH PROBLEM: Mysql2::Error: Unknown column 'blah' in 'order clause': SELECT COUNT(*) AS count_all, users.id AS id FROM `users` INNER JOIN `foos` ON `foos`.`user_id` = `users`.`id` left join tabley_things b on users.id = b.user_id GROUP BY users.id  ORDER BY blah DESC LIMIT 25 OFFSET 0
```

I am actually calling `users.empty?` but the `empty?` method calls `count`. When not ordering by `blah`, everything works as expected - the data paginates into a table and I can call `users.each do |user|`...`user.blah` with no problems.

Question: How to achieve what the code is doing, without encountering this same error.

Comment: Can you post the full query returned in the error?

Comment: Done! It seems to be such that if you do `select users.name from users order by users.id` it works even though `id` is not in the select statement... and that among all the rails code, rails drops the selects but keeps the ordering before doing a count query.

Answer (score 0):

If we postulate that this is a bug in Rails, and that the problem is solely with the `count` method, can do `users.to_a.count`; or in this specific case of it being the `.empty?` method being called from the application, use `users.to_a.empty?`